# OpenVPN Port Forwarding

Tags: nginx, vpn, openvpn, port-forwarding

**My current setup with example values:**

- local IP: 192.168.1.42 (server)
- application on port 6000 on this machine (server)
- public IP: 80.1.2.3 (router)
- port forwarding from 80.1.2.3:80 (router) to 192.168.1.42:80 (server)
- domain name: example.org
- DNS from example.org -> 80.1.2.3
- nginx server running (server) with reverse proxy listening on port 80 forwarding       example.org/application requests to port 6000

**What I can do:**

From the internet I can access now my application on my servers port 6000 by calling example.org/application.

So far so good. That is working fine until here!

**What I want to do now:**

I would like to run a VPN on my server (server) with OpenVPN and still be able to access my application via example.org/application from the internet.

The VPN is working fine in general as well. I configured and started it and now my puplic IP is shown to be: 100.5.6.7

**My problem:**

(Obviously) I can't access my application on my server (server) on port 6000 anymore from the internet calling example.org/application

I don't know what I need to configure now to be able to access it again?!

1. Do I need to change the DNS from my router pubic IP to my VPN public IP, so
   example.org -> 100.5.6.7 instead of example.org -> 80.1.2.3?
2. Do I need to do port forwarding in OpenVPN, which is listening to UDP 443 to port 80 TCP for my nginx server?

Comment: Don't use port 443 for OpenVPN, and don't use TCP for VPN unless you know what you're doing very well and you have meaningful reasons. It seems you don't know things very well, so it is best for you to stick with defaults, which is UDP port 1194 for OpenVPN. And yes, you need to forward it to OpenVPN server on the router to the server where OpenVPN runs. But it is better to run VPN on the router.